# Why is color picked from Color Meter on Mac different from color expressed in RGB in CSS and How can I get the original color

Tags: css, google-chrome, rendering, rgb, color-profile

[image]

I have noticed that there are color profiles in MacOS, which may result in this. My questions are:

1. What is the theory behind this?
2. How can I calculate the color from one profile to another (in math)?
3. What color profile is Chrome or other browser is using? does it default to the system using one?